# SAP Business One Mailer Gmail and Office 365

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, office365, sapb1

I'm trying to configure SBO mailer to work with a service email account setup in our Office 365 account. I've tried with a normal Gmail account and the mail service works perfectly. However when I apply the same settings and logic with the Office 365 account the mail just remains in the SAP outbox.

I've checked the SAP logs and the Operation completed successfully [Message 200-48] and I don't get much info from the windows event viewer either.

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I have to assume its something from the Office 365 side of things because the SBO mailer service works with a standard Gmail account.

Settings I used for the Office 365 account are:

- smtp: `smtp.office365.com`
- port: `587`
- Encryption method: *TLS*
- Username and password have been confirmed and work.

Any help will be hugely appreciated.
Thanks
B

Answer (score 0):

SBO Mailer doesn't currently support Office 365 / TLS. I have a number of customer wanting this and we've  logged it with SAP support, but they haven't given a date for 365/TLS integration with SBO Mailer.

There are a number of suggestions on google, but so far I haven't managed to get any to work. We ended up get one of our developers to build our own mailer that supports Office 365 / TLS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi JPC12. Thanks for the response. Here's a video I found that I'm yet to try - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nl97f_Bkzgc. It looks at using Windows Power shell to connect Office 365 in a way that allows the service account "SAP@business.com" to send emails from SBO mailer on behalf of the users respective accounts. I'm not familiar with Windows Power Shell so I haven't attempted it yet. Have you looked at this at all? It seems to work somehow.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Yes I've do believe I've seen this before, but much like yourself I'm not not familiar with Power Shell either so couldnt get it to work. I did notice something the other day though, I'm just about the start a SAP HANA implementation. I configured the linux server yesterday and noticed that the SBO Mailer does work with 365 / TLS on HANA, so I'm not sure if they are only developing this for the HANA environment for now and then releasing for SQL somewhere down the line.